# Airflow DAG not running as per schedule

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Airflow DAG is not getting triggered. DAG is scheduled to run every Sunday at
15:15 UTC

DAG worked well during the test but same DAG did not (get triggered) run in production.
The below code was 
scheduled to run on July 9th, 2019 (Tuesday) at 15:15 UTC and it worked

```
---Test Code

args={
      "owner":"***",
      "start_date":datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 9),
      'retries': 3,
      'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='**_scoring_test',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='15 15 * * 2',
    catchup=False,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60)
)
```

When we deployed in production to run on Sunday (July 14th, 2019) 15:15 UTC it did not run.
No logs found at `~/airflow/logs/**_scoring_prod`

Here is the production code

```
-- Production Code
args={
      "owner":"EB",
      "start_date":datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 9),
      'retries': 3,
      'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='**_scoring_prod',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='15 15 * * 0',
    catchup=False,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60)
)
```

Any suggestion why prod DAG did not get triggered but test worked well

Comment: Can you share `executor` value from airflow.cfg? in both staging and production ?

Comment: ```executor = CeleryExecutor```

Comment: are you seeing any errors in scheduler logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you created dag after `15 15 * * 0` on 9th then it will run on next Sunday i.e. on
21st.

To solve your problem you can use start date as `(2019, 7, 9) -1` day.

Comment: The prod DAG was created on July 9th 23:19 UTC. 
The test DAG was created on July 8th 19:21. 
They both have the same ```start_date``` but different  ```schedule_interval```.
You mentioned "solve your problem you can use start date as (2019, 7, 9)", ```start_date``` is already  (2019, 7, 9) .

Comment: can you try start_date  (2019, 6, 9)

Comment: Any reason why  start_date (2019, 6, 9)?

Comment: my thinking is when you give start date (2019,7,9) dag will run on (2019,7,21) for the first time.